# A c program to convert from octal to decimal

Tags: c, arrays, loops, stdout, stdin

I'm trying to figure what is wrong with my code as it always skips only to the `printf("not an octal number part");` and only outputs that although has many of the other computations before it, i'm trying to debug it but can't seem to find the error. this is the summer of the problem below, also we are not allowed to use pointers yet.

A C program to input an octal number in the form of a line of characters and store the input    characters  in  an  array. Convert the octal number to  a decimal integer and display the decimal   integer on the standard output using printf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100
int main() {

    char my_strg[MAX_SIZE];
    int c;
    int res = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n') {

        my_strg[i] = c;

        i++;
    } 
    int k = 0; 
    for(k = strlen(my_strg)-1; k >= 0; k--) {

        if((my_strg[k] >= '0') && (my_strg[k] <= '7')) {

            res +=  (pow(8, k) * (my_strg[k]-'0'));

        } else if(my_strg[k] == '-') {

            res *= -1;

        } else {
            printf("not an octal number");
            break;
        }
        k++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", res);
}
```

Comment: Make sure to null-terminate ```my_strg``` (put a ```\0``` after the last character).

Comment: do not `pow` for the integer numbers!!

Comment: Are you familiar with `strtol` family of functions?

Comment: `while (i < MAX_SIZE - 1 && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)`

Comment: @EugeneSh. sometimes people need to learn how to program. Not only how to use libraries.

Comment: @P__J__ Note, I did not say "use the library function", I just pointed that there is a standard solution if desired.

Comment: Seems like "not an octal number" is an error message. `fprintf( stderr, "not an octal number")`.  It may seem like a trivial difference, but error messages should always go to stderr.

Comment: **Never** use `pow` for this purpose. **Never**. Use repeated multiplications or bitshifts instead.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't null-terminated `my_strg`. This means that the beginning of the array contains the input, but the rest of it contains gibberish. It may also be a good idea to do bounds checking so that you don't get a buffer overflow.

```c
while (((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (i < MAX_SIZE-1)) {
    my_strg[i] = c;
    my_strg[i+1] = '\0';
    i++;
}
```

Comment: for some reason its still not working it gets an input but does not return an output

Comment: `my_strg[i+1] = '\0';` Why not bung this at the end of the while loop as `my_strg[i] = '\0';`? Efficency?

Answer (score -1):

very simple function. Needs more error checking. 
Note `'a' != 'A'`. The base can be as big as number of chars in the digits table

```
static const char digits[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTSTUWXYZ";
long long ALMOST_anybase(const char *str, int base, int *errCode)
{
    long long result = 0;
    int sign = 1;

    if(errCode) *errCode = 0;
    if(str)
    {   
        if(*str == '-') {sign = -1; str++;}
        while(*str)
        {
            if(*str == '-') 
            {
                if(errCode) *errCode = 3;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                char *ch;
                if((ch = strchr(digits, *str)))
                {
                    if(ch - digits >= base)
                    {
                        if(errCode) *errCode = 2;
                        break;
                    }
                    result *= base;
                    result += (ch - digits);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(errCode) *errCode = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            str++;
        }
    }
    return result * sign;
}


int main(void)
{
    int errCode;
    long long result;

    result = ALMOST_anybase("-4-4", 10, &errCode);
    if(errCode)
    {
        printf("Wrong input string ErrCode = %d\n", errCode);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("result = %lld\n", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: This algorithm will say that "56--7--" is a legal octal number.

Comment: @FredK if you can read - *Needs more error checking*. we do not write program here for free. This function just shows the idea.